# Appended items flow outside of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple "dice" roller, where the user can choose how many sides and how many dice based on input.

My issue is that if the user selects a large number of dice, it will force the page to scroll left in order to view the other dice.

I have tried to keep these dice within a div , even trying `word-wrap: break-word;` within the css, but this stacks the dice on top of eachother.

heres my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#autoLoadR').click(function() {
    $('#buttnLodr').html("");

    if ($('#sideNum').val() < 100) {

      if ($('#diceNum').val() < 20) {
        for (i = 0; i < $('#diceNum').val(); i++) {
          let index = i + 1;
          let roll = index;
          sidesAmount = $('#sideNum').val();

          roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * sidesAmount) + 1;

          $('#buttnLodr').append("<span id='diceBox'>" + roll + "</span>")
        }
      } else {
        alert("Please enter a number for less than 20 for number of dice")
      }
    } else {
      alert("Please enter a number less than 100 for number of sides")
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #add8e6;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 500px;
}

#spaceR {
  color: lightblue;
}

.rollMeNow {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
  font-size: 72px;
  height: 156px;
  line-height: 156px;
  width: 256px;
  background: #df1f3b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

#optionDice {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
}

#diceBox {
  border: solid;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px;
  margin: 2%;
}

#rollTable {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://aaronlilly.github.io/CDN/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="optionDice">
  <h1>Number of Dice :
    <span id='spaceR'> :</span>
    <input type="text" id="diceNum" placeholder="Dice" size="5" style="margin-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top: 4px;">
  </h1>

  <h1>Number of Sides :
    <input type="text" id="sideNum" placeholder="Sides" size="5" style="margin-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top: 4px;">
  </h1>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class="rollMeNow" caption="Populate" id="autoLoadR">Roll</div>

<br>
<h1>
  <div id='rollTable'>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- <div class="col-sm"> -->
        <div id='buttnLodr'> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

Comment: `#buttnLodr {  display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }` this may help you

Comment: Ids are SINGULAR. So change your if of `diceBox` to be a class instead

Answer (score 1):

```
#diceBox { 
  // ...
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, some other suggestions:

- you have some implicitly declared variables (`i` in your for loop and `sidesAmount` in that loop)
- use `const` instead of `let` whenever you are not re-asigning a variable
- why looping from 0, then add 1 and then store it to another variable. And then you overwrite that variable with Math.floor
- try to avoid selecting DOM elements (event if its only single) by IDs. Always use class.